# Parsing Natural Language Music Citations Using Regex

Tags: regex, nlp

I am struggling with nailing down a fairly complex regular expression to parse song titles with optional artist attribution from loosely-typed English. The user input comes from a single text field and the regex matches will be used to query a song database to get unique track IDs. I need to be able to get these matches:

- `\1` = song title
- `\2` = artist

while being fairly liberal in allowed formats.

### Examples

The wold "by" should split the string into song title and artist (but only on word boundaries); as should a comma with/without trailing whitespace:

> baby one more time by britney spears
>
> baby one more time, britney spears
>
> baby one more time,britney spears

- `\1` = baby one more time
- `\2` = britney spears

False positives like these are acceptable:

> down by the bay

- `\1` = down
- `\2` = the bay

> whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not

- `\1` = whatever people say i am
- `\2` = that's what i'm not

…assuming quotes can be used to mark a run of text as a song title explicitly:

> "down by the bay"

- `\1` = down by the bay
- `\2` not matched

> "whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not" by arctic monkeys

- `\1` = whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not
- `\2` = arctic monkeys

Single quotes should work too, but obviously not if they appear within the title:

> 'whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not'

- `\1` = whatever people say i am, that
- `\2` = s what i'm not'

Additionally, if quotes are in use, the word "by" or a comma are optional:

> "down by the bay" raffi

- `\1` = down by the bay
- `\2` = raffi

However, if there are no quotes, and more than one "by", then only the last "by" should be used as a delimiter:

> down by the bay by raffi

- `\1` = down by the bay
- `\2` = raffi

Is this even possible with a single regex? Or would the more sane way be to split it up into multiple expressions? Either way, what might this look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example, using C#:

```
var regex = @"^((""(?<title>[^""]+)""|'(?<title>[^']+)')(\s*,\s*|\s+by\s+)?|(?<title>.*)(\s*,\s*|\s+by\s+))\s*(?<artist>.*)$";

var items = new []{
    "baby one more time by britney spears",
    "baby one more time, britney spears",
    "baby one more time,britney spears",
    "down by the bay",
    "whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not",
    "\"down by the bay\"",
    "\"whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not\" by arctic monkeys",
    "'whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not'",
    "\"down by the bay\" raffi",
    "down by the bay by raffi",
};

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(item, regex, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["title"] + " - " + match.Groups["artist"]);
}
```

Output matches your specification, as far as I can tell:

```
baby one more time - britney spears
baby one more time - britney spears
baby one more time - britney spears
down - the bay
whatever people say i am - that's what i'm not
down by the bay - 
whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not - arctic monkeys
whatever people say i am, that - s what i'm not'
down by the bay - raffi
down by the bay - raffi
```

You can actually make it better for the single-quote case by allowing apostrophes inside words:

```
var regex = @"^((""(?<title>[^""]+)""|'(?<title>([^']|(?<=\w)'(?=\w))+)')(\s*,\s*|\s+by\s+)?|(?<title>.*)(\s*,\s*|\s+by\s+))\s*(?<artist>.*)$";
```

Which fixes this case:

```
whatever people say i am, that's what i'm not -
```

Here's a commented version of the regex, which explains what each part does (should be matched with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture|RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`):

```
var regex = @"
^
  (
    (
      ""(?<title>[^""]+)""               (?# matches a double-quote string )
    | '(?<title>([^']|(?<=\w)'(?=\w))+)' (?# matches a single-quote string, allowing quotes in words )
    ) (\s*,\s*|\s+by\s+)?   (?# optionally follow these by ',' or 'by' )
  | 
  (?<title>.*)(\s*,\s*|\s+by\s+) (?# otherwise, everything up to ',' or 'by' )
)
\s*(?<artist>.*) (?# everything after this is the artist name )
$";
```

*Edit:*

I've played around a bit with the PHP code, but I can't get it to use named capturing groups properly. Here is a version using unnamed capturing groups:

```
$regex = "/^(?:(?:\"([^\"]+)\"|'((?:[^']|(?<=\\w)'(?=\\w))+)')(?:\\s*,\\s*|\\s+by\\s+)?|(.*)(?:\\s*,\\s*|\\s+by\\s+))\s*(.*)\$/";

preg_match($regex, '"down by the river"', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

The title will be in group 1, 2, or 3, and the artist in group 4.

Comment: +1 @Porges for the killer regex. Hugh, if you can manipulate them well enough to do this in less than an hour, then clearly my answer is much less applicable :)

Comment: Wow, thanks a million! I want to accept, but I can't seem to get it to work in PHP (which I probably should've specified I was using) with preg_match, which returns false (meaning an error occurred), while preg_last_error reports no error. Tried this with both the commented and uncommented versions of the latter expression. Using Heredoc syntax to emulate the string literal, then passing that as `"/$regex/nxi"`. Also does not seem to work in JS as tested on [JRX](http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/).

Comment: Oh, looks like I should've been using Nowdoc since PHP still parses Heredocs. But it also doesn't support `/n`. I get the following error in my logs: "preg_match(): Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same name at offset 104" (offset 33 with the uncommented version).

Comment: Ah, it looks like PHP doesn't like multiple groups with the same name. You'll have to change the named groups (`(?<title>...)`) to something like `titleDoubleQuote`, `titleSingleQuote` and `otherTitle`, and then check each one individually. Javascript doesn't support named capturing groups, so if you want to use it there, I'd change the named groups to normal groups (just `(...)`) and convert the other ones to non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`).

Comment: OK, I did that. It no longer throws an error, but some of the test cases are breaking. For instance, using double quotes only and no artist:
`Array
(
    [0] => "down by the bay"
    [titleDoubleQuote] => 
    [1] => 
    [titleSingleQuote] => 
    [2] => 
    [otherTitle] => "down
    [3] => "down
    [artist] => the bay"
    [4] => the bay"
)`

Comment: I was able to arrive at a workable solution in PHP, but it splits the processing up into multiple, somewhat-repetitive expressions with conditional statements, as @shelleybutterfly suggested, which I can post. Although I'm still quite interested in what it'd look like as one expression in PHP, you don't have to go to the trouble if you don't want to. Unless there's any kind of performance gain to be had by doing it that way?

Comment: @Hugh: I updated the post at the same time as I posted that comment. It's at the end :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the examples you've posted, I certainly wouldn't try to write a single regex for all cases, unless there was some compelling reason to do so. Writing such an expression, which I do imagine is possible, would be very brittle, and would likely be a hassle to maintain.

Sounds like you just have some simple rule-based processing, which I would treat as such.  You could have each of the individual rule be a regex, store them in whatever order you like, and then as you got more experience with processing you could try to figure out whether there was a better order, perhaps depending on the percentage that were parsed the way you would like.

Just iteratively try to refine your rules; you might start to notice more complex patterns and you could expand your rules classes to take multiple steps into account for one rule, e.g. perhaps you notice that for a particular rule, it's failing, but that if you were to add an additional check to that rule you could weed out most of the failures.

As for each regex, I think probably simplest is best, and none of the individual rules would likely need to be that complicated, especially at first. Regular expressions are very powerful tools, but I wouldn't focus too much on trying to shoehorn something like parsing natural language into something that is more well-suited for parsing well-defined formal languages.  (Thus, the "regular" part.)

One more idea that comes to me off the top of my head would be to consider that you might find in certain cases that running some sort of conformance on the input text could make the processing easier, for instance by reducing the number of cases you have to process. To use a (possibly good or bad) example from the provided examples, instead of having a rule to process `X by Y` and a rule to process `X, Y` and a rule to process `"X" Y`, you could run a filter that replaces `by[space]` with `,` one that replaces `,[space]` with `,` and one that replaces `"X"[space]` with `X,`.  Then at the end you're *only* left with `X,Y` which means you only have to process the one case.  Likely too simplistic of an example to be useful, but it's a good pattern to be able to search for; sometimes conformance can greatly simplify this kind of processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would go a more *statistical/spam-filter* way and reduce the natural language to an array of words, then measure the distance among the words that compose the title and the artist's name.

In *regexp terms* this may mean transforming every normal word (`\w+`) in a single `-` and every word in the title and author in a `!`

*But that's just a fancy way to visualize word runs.*